# PHPBREW installing imap support error

Tags: php, linux, apache, imap

I am trying to install a phpbrew extension because of the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in /var/www/html/mainframe/mailer.php on line 30
```

I have recieved the following in my CLI window after the function to install has been run :

Install code:

```
phpbrew extension install imap
```

Results:

```
      PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/COMPUTERNAME/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.10/etc/php.ini on line 8
    ===> Installing imap extension...
    Log stored at: /home/COMPUTERNAME/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.10/ext/imap/build.log
    Changing directory to /home/COMPUTERNAME/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.10/ext/imap
    ===> Phpize...
    ===> Configuring...
    Exception: Command failed: ./configure --with-php-config=/home/COMPUTERNAME/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.10/bin/php-config >> /home/COMPUtERNAME/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.10/ext/imap/build.log 2>&1 returns
    Trace:

    0) PhpBrew\Utils::system('./configure --with-php-config=/home/COMPUTERNAME/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.10/bin/php-config >> /home/COMPUTERNAME/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.10/ext/imap/build.log 2>&1', CLIFramework\Logger)
    1) PhpBrew\Extension\ExtensionInstaller->install(PhpBrew\Extension\M4Extension, [])
    2) PhpBrew\Extension\ExtensionManager->installExtension(PhpBrew\Extension\M4Extension, [])
    3) PhpBrew\Command\ExtensionCommand\InstallCommand->execute('imap')
    4) call_user_func_array([PhpBrew\Command\ExtensionCommand\InstallCommand, 'execute'], ['imap'])
    5) CLIFramework\CommandBase->executeWrapper(['imap'])
    6) CLIFramework\Application->run(['/usr/bin/phpbrew', 'extension', 'install', 'imap'])
    7) CLIFramework\Application->runWithTry(['/usr/bin/phpbrew', 'extension', 'install', 'imap'])
    8) require('phar:///usr/bin/phpbrew/scripts/phpbrew-emb.php')
```

root@mainframe:~#

Comment: What OS do you have?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the phpbrew php version. You can look with phpbrew list what for a php version you currently use.